# How can I select file and folder from same input box in html

Tags: html

Hi I have `HTML` code which only select folder . I need to select file and folder using same input block
Here is my `HTML` code

`<input type="file" multiple id="file-input"  webkitdirectory="" directory="" />`

Answer (score 0):

The property webkitdirectory let the user select directories instead of files (and  is non-standard). If you need to select files just use `<input type="file"  id="file-input" multiple />`

Comment: But I need to select folder also

Comment: The input type="file" use is for upload content (files) to the server. Why do you need to upload a local folder path? Anyway, for security reasons neither HTML nor javascript allows you to send any information about the client's File System (unless the client himself type it into a text field). Even with webkitdirectory you only get the relative path.

Comment: I need to get the folder so that I can compress the folder and upload it to the server

Comment: By no means javascript or HTML allow compress a folder from the Client's File System. If you need to manipulate it you should use an ActiveX, an Applet or a browser plugin for that purpose. Be aware that this technologies are been deprecated due to security risks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use The accept attribute to specify the types of files that the server accepts here is an example of use

```
<input accept="file_extension|audio/*|video/*|image/*|media_type">
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Here if give this it is showing a input box instead of button